# Cannot modify subset of psp object

Tags: r, spatstat

All,

I am trying to modify a subset of a psp object in the R package spatstat. Here is the code that is giving me an issue:

```
   set.seed(10)
   mat <- matrix(runif(40), ncol=4)
   mx <- data.frame(v1=sample(1:4,10,TRUE),
                    v2=factor(sample(letters[1:4],10,TRUE),levels=letters[1:4]))
   a <- as.psp(mat, window=owin(),marks=mx)
   #subset to marking v1 = 2, modify one of its endpoints
   a[a$marks$v1==2]$ends$x0<-rep(5,4)
```

this throws a warning at me:

> Warning message:
> In a[a$marks$v1 == 2]$ends$x0 <- rep(5, 4) :
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

What is the right way to modify some elements of a psp object? I commonly use this operation with dataframes and don't have an issue. My sense is that the subset operator ([) isn't set up for this operation with the psp class.

Thank you for reading; appreciate any help you may have.

Comment: Are you sure `a[a$marks$v1 == 2]$ends$x0` does have length 3?

Comment: thanks for the note -- I hadn't updated the warning message with the set.seed update to this post. It still gives the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to write to a subset of the `psp` object. Although the `[` operator is defined for this class so you can *extract a subset from it*, the `[<-` operator is not defined, so you can't *overwrite a subset*.

However, the member that you are trying to overwrite is a data frame, which of course does have a `[<-` operator defined. So all you need to do is write to that without subsetting the actual `psp` object.

Here's a full reprex:

```r
library(spatstat)

set.seed(10)
mat <- matrix(runif(40), ncol = 4)
mx  <- data.frame(v1 = sample(1:4, 10, TRUE),
                  v2 = factor(sample(letters[1:4], 10, TRUE),
                              levels = letters[1:4]))
a <- as.psp(mat, window = owin(), marks = mx)

#subset to marking v1 = 2, modify one of its endpoints
a$ends$x0[a$marks$v1 == 2] <- rep(5, 4)

a
#> marked planar line segment pattern: 10 line segments
#> Mark variables:  v1, v2
#> window: rectangle = [0, 1] x [0, 1] units
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I will take that as a feature request to add a method for `[<-` for class `psp`.

Generally we advise against directly altering the components of objects in `spatstat` because this can destroy their internal consistency. So a method for `[<-` would be the best solution.

Comment: I did have a peek at the internals of the `psp` object to make sure this particular operation didn't break the internal consistency, and it seemed OK. I understand the bigger picture of advising against this kind of thing in general though. From an end user point of view, perhaps all that is needed for the `[<-` operator is an error message effectively saying "you can't do that` - at the moment the error message is unclear.